# How can I send and receive WebSocket messages on the client side?

Tags: encoding, protocols, websocket, arduino

- How do I encode messages to be sent from the client to comply with the latest [WebSocket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)?
- Framing and masking seem to be the issue with the latest version. What is the easiest way to generate correct framing and masking client side?

Answer (score 0):

If your message are all less than or equal to 125 bytes, and if you are just sending from the  client (and never receiving) then you can use a really trivial algorithm.

Here is how you would construct a frame to send using python:

```
"\x81%c\x00\x00\x00\x00%s" % (128 + len(payload), payload)
```

Or alternately, here is how you could do it in C:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...
char frame[131];
frame[0] = '\x81';
frame[1] = 128 + strlen(payload);
frame[2] = '\x00';
frame[3] = '\x00';
frame[4] = '\x00';
frame[5] = '\x00';
snprintf(frame+6, 125, "%s", payload);
```

**Explanation:**

- The first byte 0x81 means that this is the final (and only) frame of this message (i.e. no fragmentation).
- The next byte is the mask and the length. Client to server messages must be masked so the top bit is set. If the payload is longer than 125 bytes then the payload field extends another 2 or 8 bytes in the header. Since it's not, it's easy.
- Since the mask is a running XOR on payload, using all zeros for the mask means that the payload can be send as is (e.g. XOR'ing with zeros is a no-op).
- If you device is going to run arbitrary untrusted then (e.g. Javascript in a browser) then you should use a real random mask value. If this is an Arduino device running your own code then there is no issue and you can use a no-op mask (you still have to have a mask according to the spec).

If you want to go beyond the trivial case I suggest looking at the framing diagram in [section 5 of the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the framing diagram.  What is the python syntax for encoding longer messages?  How long can the message be?

Comment: @shaun5, If the frame length is 126-65535 bytes, then the byte 1 length value is 126, and then length is encoded in bytes 2 and 3. If the payload is longer than 65535 bytes, then 127 is put in byte 1, and bytes 2-9 have the payload length. Theoretically the payload could be 2^64 bytes long (16 billion gigabytes), but no clients or servers support that yet.